# Couldnt call method on FlatList renderRow?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I have a simple `FlatList` with list of youtube videos as below:

```
<FlatList 
  data={this.props.videoList}
  renderItem={this.renderRow}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.videoId.toString()}
/>
```

And for each and every `renderRow` function I need an API call to retrieve number of Likes from `YOUTUBE API` and return a component as below:

```
renderRow({ item }) {
  const something = this.getIndividualStatistics(item);
  return (<SomeComponent />);
}
```

And below is the function for `getIndividualStatistics`

```
getIndividualStatistics = async item => {
  const { data } = await axios.get('youtubeAPI bla bla bla');
  return data;
}
```

And I get error while trying to load this `FlatList`

[image]

Comment: I am just wondering if renderRow function giving you correct result ?  is it synchronous ? or you get empty SomeComponent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `renderRow` in constructor, otherwise `this` in `renderRow` will be referencing itself:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
}
```

Alternatively declare `renderRow` as arrow function:

```
renderRow = ({ item }) => {
```

See [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56) for more info.

Comment: Ahhhh it's because of this mistake yet again...omg wondering when can I really master this. Thanks a lot! will mark as answer as soon as I can